# ClearMap2 - Cell alignment section - file not found error

Tags: python

Encountering an error when running this cell, does any one know how to fix it? Thank you.
cfos and autofluo images have been resampled align with the template/reference file in atlas. Is it necessary to debug this file?

File "/homeanaconda3/envs/ClearMapStable/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 4696, in open
self._fh = open(self._file, self._mode)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ClearMap2/Documentation/Example/Haloperidol/haloperidol/1268/debug_resampled.tif'

Comment: Have you checked that file location to see if the specified image is there?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all responding.

I've solved this problem. It simply need to turn on the debug mode at the beginning of the script. In my case, I turned on the change the code to 'ws.debug = True' in the Initialize workspace cell.